# Clicking on a button with dynamic selector in python selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, ember.js, webdriverwait

I am working on this automation thing and I am trying to click on this button with selector

```
<button id="ember2570" class="ember-view btn btn-default btn btn-default" type="button">    <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
PDMLink<!----></button>
```

I have tried find_element_by_id but the ID changes with every reload and the class names are also not unique to the button.
if I try including wildcard like "ember*" then it clicks somewhere else. Almost all the elements of the web page has id="ember*someRandomNumber*"
I cannot share the url as it is an intranet site.

Comment: Hm, what about the `fa-upload` class of the child? Is it used somewhere else on that page?

Comment: its an icon and yes it is used somewhere else as well. There are 6 buttons and all have same class names. the difference between them is the ID and the button text.

Comment: Ugh. What about contents of that button tag? Are there any differences? Because if the 'button with ember and child i.fa-upload' is too broad, we need to dig further! Or is your desired button always n-th in the view? Then we can find all and just take n-th.

Comment: @Devbrath_R if you are looking for the button with the specific text you can use xpath... see the edit in my answer...

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS Selector:

The Operator `^` - Match element that starts with the given value.

In your case:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[id^="ember"] i.fa-upload')
```

Using XPath:

The keyword `contains` Match element that contains the given value.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@id,'ember')/i[contains(@class,'fa-upload')]")
```

## Edit:

If you are looking for the button with the text of "PDMLink":

You can use `text` in the XPath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='PDMLink']")
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is how i would approach this simple "problem":

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[id^="ember"] i.fa-upload").click()
```

If click doesnt work, then you can also import keys and do .send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
I havent worked with selenium in quite a bit so give that a try and let me know.

I usually work with my own API i built last year which has functions like type(), find(), find_path(), find_id(), click() and all of them are built to avoid capcha cashe from building and avoiding most of those "im not a robot" things which crash bots. I just use time delays at random intervals. The type() actually recieves the string and types char by char on a small time delay which is always random and that is the main thing

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned *...the ID changes with every reload and the class names are also not unique to the button...*  additionally the desired element is a [Ember.js](https://www.emberjs.com/) enabled element so to `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='ember-view btn btn-default btn btn-default' and contains(., 'PDMLink')][.//i[@class='fa fa-upload']]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```